# Selenium Getting Hover Textbox Text

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver, eclipse

I am working in eclipse writing selenium scripts using Java. I am using the chrome web driver. I have a hyper text link that when I put my mouse over it hover text box appears. I need to return that string to verify it. How can I return that text in a string? The problem I am having is that I cannot put my mouse over the hover text box to find the element because the hover text box disappears so there is no way for me to just easily put the dev tools over the text box to get the text.

Comment: Just vote me down with give no reason, that should not be allowed. This is a valid question with all the relevant information and I checked the database for any duplicate questions so wtf.

Comment: While I didn't down vote, my guess is missing code samples? It can be very helpful to see the code from the DOM you're working with and the code you're written to try to accomplish this task.

Comment: Is it a question or statement , what's the actual problem

Comment: @PDHide "I have an element that is some text that I can hover over and that brings up a hover text box with a bunch of text in it. How can I get that text?"

Comment: Did the answer help

Comment: @PDHide I updated my post, no you that did no help me sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example on how to get the text of tool tip:

```
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/prave/Desktop/push.html");
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.className("tooltip"))).build().perform();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("tooltiptext")));
    System.out.println(element.getText());
```

You have to use action class for hovering and use getText after using wait for visibility of .

**html used for above example:**

just copy this and save as an html file to try out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  
  /* Fade in tooltip - takes 1 second to go from 0% to 100% opac: */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Fade In Tooltip on Hover</h2>
<p>When you move the mouse over the text below, the tooltip text will fade in and take 1 second to go from completely invisible to visible.</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">extract text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```